# Sharepoint includes control template twice

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2010

I'm working on a SharePoint 2010 project. We have a usercontrol to include all of our custom javascript. I popped an alert in there whilst debugging something else, and lo and behold the alert was called twice. I checked and the file in question is included by only one Elements.xml file in one feature. So how can this be? I've tried searching the whole solution, and I only get one hit, so I must be missing something.

EDIT:

This is the code calling the User Control:

```
<Control Id="AdditionalPageHead" Sequence="10" ControlSrc="/_controltemplates/company/UCLoadJS.ascx" />
```

This code is found in the Elements.xml of the MasterPages folder, which deploys our custom master page.
Having searched the whole project for UCLoadJS, I cannot find another instance.

Comment: How are you including the control: delegate, on a page layout? Some code on how you're doing it would be better.

Comment: There I've edited the question a bit to add some code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you have hidden WPs loading these Controls.
Try creating a new page and add the Visual WP once and try again

Comment: The only place this UC is loaded is directly in the master page. No webpart loads it at all.

Answer (score 0):

I know that this question is 9 years old but I just had the same problem, so in case someone stumble across this thread, maybe this will help you:

- try to list all your delegate controls. you can slightly modify the script provided by Waldek Mastykarz : [Checking which Delegate Controls are activated on your site](https://blog.mastykarz.nl/checking-which-delegate-controls-activated-site/)
- if you find duplicated controls (and that was the situation in my case) then its probably because you deployed your control using one feature scope (Site for example) and then redeployed with another one (Web). Follow the steps below to solve the problem:

1). switch to another feature scope (the one you no longer want to use)

2). deploy the feature

3). deactivate it

4). switch feature scope to the required one and redeploy it

Source: [SharePoint delegate control is rendered twice](https://maxim-dikhtyaruk.blogspot.com/2014/04/sharepoint-delegate-control-is-rendered.html?m=1)